# Get number of connected users in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

While I'm trying to detach a database through Enterprise Manager, it shows the no. of users accessing the database and it didn't allow us to detach without clearing the database connection.

Well, I want to know whether the result (no. of users connecting a particular database) could be obtained through a SQL query?  If yes, how ?

Happiness Always
BKR Sivaprakash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you proper results. Add your database name in the query -

```
select spid, status, loginame, 
hostname, blocked, db_name(dbid) as databasename, cmd 
from master..sysprocesses
where db_name(dbid) like '%<database_name>%'
and spid > 50
```

This will include logins from SQL Agent. Note that the
same user can be using multiple connections from the same application,
and thus be counted more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC SP_WHO
```

or

```
EXEC SP_WHO2
```

maybe (think this might be SQL Server 2005 upwards):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ConnectionCount,
CASE WHEN is_user_process =1 THEN 'UserProcess' ELSE 'System Process' END
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
GROUP BY is_user_process
```